# How do I iterate through nested pandas dataframe by column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, iteration

**Problem:** I have a 1 row dataframe `dfA` whose column length can vary, within each cell contains a json object. All fields in each json object are the same.

I'm trying to write code that loops through each cell, parses the JSON object, and loads ALL data into 1 single dataframe `dfB`, so if I have 5 columns in `dfA` then the final output of `dfB` should have 5 rows

I have the code written to where I can manually enter the column number of `dfA` and `dfB` outputs correctly:

```
dataA = dfA[0].values.tolist()
dfB = pd.json_normalize(dataA)
dfB
```

In the above example, the code pulls the 1st JSON object of `dfA` and correctly outputs a 1 row dataframe

**I've Tried:**

```
for column in dfA:
  dataA = dfA[column].values.tolist()
  dfB = pd.json_normalize(dataA)
```

This outputs just the last cell in `dfA`

I've tried different variations of this and either get the 1st cell, last cell, or the original `dfA`

Please help, thank you!

**EDIT:**

```
dfA:
```

|  | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | {'id':'testID434556'... | {'id':'testID568912'... | {'id':'testID652154'... | {'id':'testID756298'... | {'id':'testID812362'... |

```
dataA = dfA[0].values.tolist()
dfB = pd.json_normalize(dataA)
dfB
```

|  | id | field2 | field3 | field4 | field5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | testID434556 | field2data | field3data | field4data | field5data |

Desired Output:

|  | id | field2 | field3 | field4 | field5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | testID434556 | field2data | field3data | field4data | field5data |
| 1 | testID568912 | field2data | field3data | field4data | field5data |
| 2 | testID652154 | field2data | field3data | field4data | field5data |
| 3 | testID756298 | field2data | field3data | field4data | field5data |
| 4 | testID812362 | field2data | field3data | field4data | field5data |

Comment: Will you please provide a small sample of the dataframe?

Comment: Just updated with what it looks like now and what I'm trying to get to, thank you!

Comment: For each column you loop over with your for loop, you create a different dfB. You need to store it, for instance 
`dfB = pd.DataFrame()
for column in dfA:
  dataA = dfA[column].values.tolist()
  dfB = pd.concat([dfB, pd.json_normalize(dataA)])
`

Answer (score 0):

`dfA[0]` only gets the first column. You should convert you dataframe first row to list then feed the result to `pd.json_normalize()`

```py
pd.json_normalize((dfA.iloc[0, :].values))
```